# Rewrite rule and Redirect of URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Simply put have some 300 URLs that have the same pattern in the middle of the URL and want to have it redirect to another location with a change in the middle while the rest of the URL is the same. They all have the URL convention of http://www.domainname.com/blog/tag/some-content/ AND I want to be able to redirect all of them to http://www.domainname.com/tag/some-content/ where the subfolder /some-content/ remains the same while /blog/tag/ change to just /tag/. Seemed simple so I tried this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^tag/(.*) /blog/tag/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

But it ultimately removes the rest of the URL AND/OR doesn't work. Lost, I am.

Comment: I think you might need to escape the forward slash character. Have you tried something like this? `^tag\/(.*)`

Comment: If you want to redirect it use **R** flag, [NC,R,L]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They all have the URL convention of http://www.domainname.com/blog/tag/some-content/ AND I want to be able to redirect all of them to http://www.domainname.com/tag/some-content/

Sounds like you want:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/tag/(.*)/$ /tag/$1
```

or (using mod_rewrite)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/tag/(.*)/$ /tag/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: This did work for me "RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/tag/(.*)/$ /tag/$1". Thank you! I also had to place it in front of a few other rewriterules to take precedent before others could take affect.  Appreciate your help Jon Lin and others!